# Selecting Entire Cells with Value (Non-Continuous)

Tags: vba, excel

My data starts at A3 and want to select entire cells with value.

Just like if you were to Ctrl+A to select.

Row A1 and A2 is Header stuff and merged together.

`UsedRange` select from A1
`End(xlto...)` won't work due to non-continuous data.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("A3").CurrentRegion
```

is the same as selecting A3 then Ctrl+A, but you describe having data in rows 1 and 2, so you probably want something more like

```
Dim rng as Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("A3"), _
                 .Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)).Resize(,numColumns)
End With
```

where `numColumns` is how many columns of data you have

Comment: Perfect! Easy solution it seems. Thank you Tim!